# Unix: extract a part of the filename and rename the file with the new name

Tags: shell, unix, awk, cygwin

I have a directory containing a list of csv files i.e

```
short-books-for-sale.csv
old-books-for-sale.csv
random-books-for-sale-new.csv
```

I want to use a UNIX command to change all file names in the directory. when renaming the files i want to remove everything after the word "books".
the output will look something like this:

```
short-books.csv
old-books.csv
random-books.csv
```

This is what I've done so far, but its still not working correctly.

```
for f in *.csv; do
awk -F'books' '{print FILENAME}' "$f";
mv "$f" "$f";
done
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure what you thought `awk -F'books' '{print FILENAME}' "$f"` or `mv "$f" "$f"` would do but what they actually do is:

```
awk -F'books' '{print FILENAME}' "$f"
```

=> read file "$f" line by line, split each line at every occurrence of `books` and do nothing further with that but instead print the value of "$f" once for every line in "$f".

```
mv "$f" "$f"
```

=> attempt to move file "$f" to itself. That will obviously produce an error message as it makes no sense.

Try this:

```
for f in *books-*.csv; do
    echo mv -- "$f" "${f/books-*./books.}"
done
```

Remove the `echo` when you're done testing so it becomes just:

```
for f in *books-*.csv; do
    mv -- "$f" "${f/books-*./books.}"
done
```

Answer (score 0):

With `prename` (Perl rename) *one-liner* (if supported):

```
prename 's/books[^.]+/books/' *.csv
```